# How to use R to return max value of one column and the contents of the corresponding row following column

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this but much longer:

```
A   B
1   0
3   9
7   3
6   2
1   4
2   1
```

I want to get the maximum value of column A and the value in column B that corresponds with it, regardless of whether it is also the maximum value. So for this data set I would like to get 7 and 3. But if I use:

```
Max<-apply(df,2,max)
```

I get 7 and 9.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You want the row at which `A` has its maximum: `df[which.max(df$A), ]`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   slice(which.max(A))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#      A     B
#   <int> <int>
#1     7     3
```